Vite not showing full logs
I'm currently getting the below error when running npx vite build.
vite v5.2.9 building for production...
✓ 21 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 34ms
error during build:
RollupError: Expression expected
    at getRollupError (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:392:41)
    at ParseError.initialise (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:11170:28)
    at convertNode (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12915:10)
    at convertProgram (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12232:12)
    at Module.setSource (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14076:24)
    at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///Users/rtan0090/git/portal-workspace/frontend-common/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18729:13)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I am hoping to find out which file was causing the above error?
I have also run npx vite build -d for logs, but none of them seem to pertain to the error in question.
I have also run npx vite build -d for logs, but none of them seem to pertain to the error in question.
